# Design improvement suggestion

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, design-patterns, optimization

I am working on legacy java/j2ee project which is using Servlets/JSP/JDBC, it has been evolving since long hence there is no framework involved. However we have followed command pattern for servlets and done same basic application of OOP's concepts. We don't have Service layer nor the DAO layer . Below is the basic design of application.

All servlets extend a base servlet , This base Servlet holds the DB connection variable ( which is a instance variable) .
All the Beans(VO's) hold the code for getting data from DB too along with Setter and getter code . Each Bean has connection variable ( instance variable)

Each time a servlet gets invoked it calls the Super servlet to get connection object ( the servlet get the connection object using DB-util class using Data-source)  and when servlet wants to get any data from DB it calls the respective Bean and sets the connection object and the bean performs all the DB operation using plain old JDBC code once the Bean is done with fetching of data and control goes back to servlet the servlet closes the connection before forwarding to JSP.

Now I want to improve the design , I know i can bring in service/DAO layer but this is time consuming as the application has about 300-400  Beans ( we also have 300 tables) this would take at-least 3-4 months with 5-10 resources .

Super Servlet , this is extended by all Servlets.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class SuperServlet extends HttpServlet implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4550230842458337348L;

    private java.sql.Connection conn = null;


public boolean callJSP(
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, Connection con)
    throws Exception {


    String userId = null;
    String userGrp = null;
    SessionUIBean userInfo = (SessionUIBean) request
            .getSession().getAttribute("userInfo");


    String jsp=(String)request.getAttribute("JspName");
    String NAS_PREFIX = "user/jsp/";
    String VAJ_PREFIX = "/";
    String jspName = VAJ_PREFIX +jsp;
    logger.debug("@@@@@ jspName : " +jspName);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(jspName);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);


    if (null != userInfo) {
        userId = userInfo.getUserID();
        if(!userId.equalsIgnoreCase("ERROR")){
            logger.info("User ID:" + userId + " -> URL : "  + request.getRequestURI() +" -> IP Address : "
                    + request.getRemoteAddr());
                if(null!=userInfo.getAdminAuthorty() && userInfo.getAdminAuthorty().equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
                    logger.info("User ID:" + userId + " -> ROLE/ADMIN AUTHORTY:SUPER ADMIN");
                }else{
                    logger.info("User ID:" + userId + " -> ROLE/ADMIN AUTHORTY:NORMAL User");
                }
            }
            // END REQ ID #338
        }
    if(con!=null){
        con.commit();
        con.close();
    }   
    return true;
    }


public boolean callJSP(
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, Connection con,Connection con2)
        throws Exception {

        //Logging and Monitor REQ ID #338
        String userId = null;
        String userGrp = null;
        SessionUIBean userInfo = (SessionUIBean) request
                .getSession().getAttribute("userInfo");
        // END

        String jsp=(String)request.getAttribute("JspName");
        String NAS_PREFIX = "user/jsp/";
        String VAJ_PREFIX = "/";
        String jspName = VAJ_PREFIX +jsp;

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(jspName);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        if (null != userInfo) {
            userId = userInfo.getUserID();
            if(!userId.equalsIgnoreCase("ERROR")){
                logger.info("User ID:" + userId + " -> URL : "  + request.getRequestURI() +" -> IP Address : "
                        + request.getRemoteAddr());
                    if(null!=userInfo.getAdminAuthorty() && userInfo.getAdminAuthorty().equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
                        logger.info("User ID:" + userId + " -> ROLE/ADMIN AUTHORTY:SUPER ADMIN");
                    }else{
                        logger.info("User ID:" + userId + " -> ROLE/ADMIN AUTHORTY:NORMAL User");
                    }
                }
                // END REQ ID #338
            }

        if(con!=null){
            con.commit();
            con.close();
        }
        if(con2!=null){
            con2.commit();
            con2.close();
        }
        return true;
        }



public Connection  connTask() throws Exception {
    java.sql.Connection connection = null;



    connection = DBUtil.createConnection();

    if (connection.getAutoCommit())
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    return connection;
}



public void displayErrorJSP(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    Throwable t,Connection con) {
    try {
        if(con!=null){
            con.rollback();
        }

        boolean displayErrorInJSP = false;
        SessionUIBean userInfo = (SessionUIBean) request.getSession()
                .getAttribute("userInfo");
        if (null != userInfo) {         
            displayErrorInJSP = userInfo.getDisplayError();
        }       
        request.setAttribute("error", new ErrorReporter(t, "",
                displayErrorInJSP));        

        request.setAttribute("JspName","Common/ServletErrorInfo.jsp");
        callJSP(request, response,con);
    } catch (Exception sql) {
        logger.error("Exception:" + sql);
    }
}

public void displayErrorJSP(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        Throwable t,Connection con,Connection con2) {
        try {
            if(con!=null){
                con.rollback();
            }
            request.setAttribute("error", new ErrorReporter(t, ""));
            request.setAttribute("JspName","Common/ServletErrorInfo.jsp");
            callJSP(request, response,con,con2);
        } catch (Exception sql) {
            logger.error("Exception:" + sql);
        }
    }



public void doGet(
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) {
    performTask(request, response);
}

public void doPost(
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) {
    performTask(request, response);
}


public void performTask(
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) {

}


}
```

Servlet Code(UserRegistrationServlet ) This servlet extends Superservlet ,it calls superservlets connTask to get connection object and the set the same value to the beans used in the servlets.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;



public class UserRegistrationServlet extends SuperServlet implements
        java.io.Serializable {


    public void performTask(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) {
        logger.info("In UserRegistrationServlet:performTask method.");
        Connection con = null;
        try {

            con = super.connTask();
            SecuUserGroupBean secuUserGroupBean = new SecuUserGroupBean();
            secuUserGroupBean.setConnection(con);
            secuUserGroupBean.getAll();
            request.setAttribute("secuUserGroupBean", secuUserGroupBean);

            SecuUserBean secuUserBean = new SecuUserBean();
            secuUserBean.setConnection(con);
            secuUserBean.getAllManagers();

            SecuFunctionBean secuFunctionBean = new SecuFunctionBean();
            secuFunctionBean.setConnection(con);
            secuFunctionBean.getAll();
            request.setAttribute("secuFunctionBean", secuFunctionBean);


            request.setAttribute("secuUserBean", secuUserBean);
            request.setAttribute("userRequestBean", userRequestBean);
            request.setAttribute("JspName", "register/usrRequest.jsp");
            callJSP(request, response, con);
        } catch (Exception theException) {
            logger.error("Exception:",theException);
            super.displayErrorJSP(request, response, theException, con);
        }
        logger.info("Exit UserRegistrationServlet:performTask method.");
    }
}
```

Bean Code , this is one of the beans code , this is stratergy followed in all the beans . As you can  see all the DB related and getter/setter code resides here . It acts both as VO and DAO.

```
import java.sql.*;



public class SecuUserGroupBean extends SuperBean {
    private String usrGrpId;
    private String usrGrpDs;
    private short appId;
    private java.sql.Date usrGrpEfctvDt;
    private java.sql.Date usrGrpXpiryDt;
    private int auditTrailId;

    //SQL Variables
    private Connection theConnection;
    private PreparedStatement selectStmt;
    private PreparedStatement actionStmt;
    private java.lang.String adminUsrId;
//  private ResultSet rs;

    private String createSQL = "INSERT INTO USR_GRP(USR_GRP_ID, USR_GRP_DS, APP_ID, USR_GRP_EFCTV_DT, USR_GRP_XPIRY_DT, ADMIN_USR_ID, AUDIT_TRAIL_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private String updateSQL = "UPDATE USR_GRP SET USR_GRP_DS = ?, APP_ID = ?, USR_GRP_EFCTV_DT = ?, USR_GRP_XPIRY_DT = ?, ADMIN_USR_ID = ?, AUDIT_TRAIL_ID = ? WHERE USR_GRP_ID = ?";

    private String deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM USR_GRP WHERE USR_GRP_ID = ?";

    private String allRecsSQL = "SELECT USR_GRP_ID, USR_GRP_DS, APP_ID, USR_GRP_EFCTV_DT, USR_GRP_XPIRY_DT, ADMIN_USR_ID, AUDIT_TRAIL_ID FROM USR_GRP WHERE USR_GRP_XPIRY_DT > current DATE ORDER BY USR_GRP_DS";

    private String pkSQL = "SELECT USR_GRP_ID, USR_GRP_DS, APP_ID, USR_GRP_EFCTV_DT, USR_GRP_XPIRY_DT, ADMIN_USR_ID, AUDIT_TRAIL_ID FROM USR_GRP WHERE USR_GRP_ID = ? AND USR_GRP_XPIRY_DT >= current DATE";

    private String selectSQL = "SELECT USR_GRP_ID, USR_GRP_DS, APP_ID, USR_GRP_EFCTV_DT, USR_GRP_XPIRY_DT, ADMIN_USR_ID, AUDIT_TRAIL_ID FROM USR_GRP WHERE ADMIN_USR_ID = ? AND USR_GRP_XPIRY_DT >= current DATE";

    private String veryfyGRPSQL = "SELECT * FROM USR_GRP GRP, TTPR_USR_ACS ACS WHERE GRP.USR_GRP_ID = ? AND GRP.USR_GRP_ID = ACS.USR_GRP_ID";

    private String updateGRPDesSQL = "UPDATE USR_GRP SET USR_GRP_DS = ?, AUDIT_TRAIL_ID = ? WHERE USR_GRP_ID = ?";

    public void updateGRPDes() throws Exception {
        boolean grpFound = false;
        actionStmt = theConnection.prepareStatement(updateGRPDesSQL);
        actionStmt.setString(1, usrGrpDs);
        actionStmt.setInt(2, auditTrailId);
        actionStmt.setString(3, usrGrpId);
        actionStmt.executeUpdate();     
        }


    public boolean verifyGRPAavail() throws Exception {
        boolean grpFound = false;
        actionStmt = theConnection.prepareStatement(veryfyGRPSQL);
        actionStmt.setString(1, usrGrpId);
        ResultSet rs =actionStmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) grpFound = false;
        else grpFound = true;   
        actionStmt.close();
        return grpFound;
    }

    public void create() throws Exception {
        // Set the parameters
        actionStmt = theConnection.prepareStatement(createSQL);
        actionStmt.setString(1, usrGrpId);
        actionStmt.setString(2, usrGrpDs);
        actionStmt.setShort(3, appId);
        actionStmt.setDate(4, usrGrpEfctvDt);
        actionStmt.setDate(5, usrGrpXpiryDt);
      actionStmt.setString(6,adminUsrId);
        actionStmt.setInt(7, auditTrailId);

        actionStmt.executeUpdate();

        actionStmt.close();
    }
    public void delete() throws Exception {
        actionStmt = theConnection.prepareStatement(deleteSQL);
        // Set the parameters
        actionStmt.setString(1, usrGrpId);

        actionStmt.executeUpdate();

        actionStmt.close();
    }
    public void findByAdminUsrId() throws SQLException {
        selectStmt = theConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);

        selectStmt.setString(1, adminUsrId);

        rs = selectStmt.executeQuery();
    }
    public boolean findByPrimaryKey() throws SQLException {
        actionStmt = theConnection.prepareStatement(pkSQL);
        actionStmt.setString(1, usrGrpId);

        ResultSet rs =actionStmt.executeQuery();

        int i = 0;

        while (rs.next()) {
            retrieve(rs);
            i++;
        }
        rs.close();
        actionStmt.close();
        if (i == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

public java.lang.String getAdminUsrId() {
    return adminUsrId;
}
    public void getAll() throws Exception {
        selectStmt = theConnection.prepareStatement(allRecsSQL);
        rs = selectStmt.executeQuery();
    }
    public int getAuditTrailId() throws Exception{
        return auditTrailId;
    }
    public short getappId() throws Exception{
        return appId;
    }
    public String getUsrGrpDs() throws Exception{
        return usrGrpDs;
    }
    public java.sql.Date getUsrGrpEfctvDt() throws Exception{
        return usrGrpEfctvDt;
    }


    public String getUsrGrpId() throws Exception{
        return usrGrpId;
    }
    public java.sql.Date getUsrGrpXpiryDt() throws Exception{
        return usrGrpXpiryDt;
    }
    public void retrieve(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        // Set the parameters
        usrGrpId = rs.getString(1);
        usrGrpDs = rs.getString(2);
        appId = rs.getShort(3);
        usrGrpEfctvDt = rs.getDate(4);
        usrGrpXpiryDt = rs.getDate(5);
        adminUsrId = rs.getString(6);
        auditTrailId = rs.getInt(7);
    }

public void setAdminUsrId(java.lang.String newAdminUsrId) {
    adminUsrId = newAdminUsrId;
}
    public void setAuditTrailId(int par_auditTrailId) throws Exception{
        auditTrailId = par_auditTrailId;
    }
    public void setConnection(Connection theConn) throws Exception {
        theConnection = theConn;

    }
    public void setappId(short par_appId) throws Exception{
        appId = par_appId;
    }
    public void setUsrGrpDs(String par_usrGrpDs) throws Exception{
        usrGrpDs = par_usrGrpDs;
    }
    public void setUsrGrpEfctvDt(java.sql.Date par_usrGrpEfctvDt) throws Exception{
        usrGrpEfctvDt = par_usrGrpEfctvDt;
    }
    public void setUsrGrpId(String par_usrGrpId) throws Exception{
        usrGrpId = par_usrGrpId;
    }
    public void setUsrGrpXpiryDt(java.sql.Date par_usrGrpXripyDt) throws Exception{
        usrGrpXpiryDt = par_usrGrpXripyDt;
    }
    public void update() throws SQLException {
        actionStmt = theConnection.prepareStatement(updateSQL);
        // Set the parameters
        actionStmt.setString(1, usrGrpDs);
        actionStmt.setShort(2, appId);
        actionStmt.setDate(3, usrGrpEfctvDt);
        actionStmt.setDate(4, usrGrpXpiryDt);
        actionStmt.setString(5,adminUsrId);
        actionStmt.setInt(6, auditTrailId);
        actionStmt.setString(7, usrGrpId);

        actionStmt.executeUpdate();

        actionStmt.close();
    }


    public void findByGroupId() throws Exception {
        selectStmt = theConnection.prepareStatement(pkSQL);     
        selectStmt.setString(1,usrGrpId);
        rs = selectStmt.executeQuery(); 
    }

    }
```

There is no problem with Connection pool , i get connection from Datasource with connection pool defined. I want a way i can make all the beans get rid of JDBC boilerplate code without introducing service/dao layer.

Is there a way by which i can improve the DB connection code and reduce JDBC boiler plate code by not bringing in the Service layer /DAO layer .

Comment: You mean to say each time servlet get invoked there will be connection object get created is it ?

Comment: I think this is what he means by "instance variable" :) I was also afraid in the beginning that he kept the db connections alive for ever! I have to read the post twice.

Comment: I get the connection from DataSource , the datasource is configured in WAS server and has connection pooling defined

Comment: @MikeArgyriou think some one needs to edit it that

Comment: Instead of describing your code, post it.

Comment: JDBC will always have tons of boiler plate... Did you consider the costly but worthy migration to JPA?

Comment: I think of all the modern frameworks hibernate,JPA my intent is to achieve optmization at less effort. Do i have rewrite whole beans if i have to migrate to JPA or hibernate